# Emails are not sending via gmail smtp server on button click android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, smtp, jakarta-mail

Hello i am developing an app in which user can sign up by filling some information.

I want to send user name, his password and a random generated code to his given email address from my own email.

I am not using intents to complete this action but directly sending mails on button click.

I am using gmail smtp server configuration for this purpose.

My code shows me the success message and moves to next activity according to my app but emails are not sending anymore.

Here is my code

```
//On button click send email to user
signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (checkValidation()){
                    sendpinCodeToMail();
                }


//send user email without opening an intent
    //send user details to given email address without opening an intent
    public void sendpinCodeToMail(){
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port","465");

        session=javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("myEmailAddress","myGooglePassword");
            }
        });
        retrivefeedTask task=new retrivefeedTask();
        task.execute();

    }
}
    });


//And here is the class where i am sending email in the background

//class to handle data to send in background email
     public class retrivefeedTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            Random random=new Random();
            int randomNo=random.nextInt(1111);
            String Subject = "Verify Your MyLife Account";
            String _Massage="Your My Life Verification Code is '"+randomNo+"' \n " +
                    "Your email address is " + email+
                    "\n Your password is "+password ;
            ///
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("pinCode",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("pin",""+randomNo);
            editor.apply();

            ///
            try {
                Message message= new MimeMessage(session);
                message.addFrom(new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress("My Life")});
                InternetAddress[] iAdressArray = InternetAddress.parse(email);
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(email));
                message.setSubject(Subject);
                message.setContent(_Massage,"text/html;charset=utf-8");
                Transport.send(message);


                Log.d("Mail ","Send");
                // Toast.makeText(context,"Mail send",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Mail ","Not Send"+"\n Error :"+e);
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error:"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           // progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CodeVerificationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",nameEt.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("email",emailEt.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("password",passwordEt.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("phone",phoneEt.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: to prevent unauthorized acces to your email you need to log into your account at Gmail.com, then open another tab and go the Less Secure Apps Setting, and select “Turn on”.

Comment: Aj Styles Less Security for my email address is on already.

Comment: FIx these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), then post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).